# Multi Threaded Port Scanner, scanning multiple IP's. How can I ensure that the ip's are scanned one at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, port

I am building a port scanner that can scan an ip range. I have got to the point where all the parameters are correct and my multithread port scanner works well for a single IP, the problem I now have is that when trying to scan a range of ip's it starts of x number of multithreaded scanners (x being the number of ip's) all at the same time and of course this is causing memory problems. I am wondering how to get the threadpools to run sequentially. Scanning a single ip at a time in order.

This is the code I have for defining my list of IP addresses and putting them into my multithread scanner.

```
        else if (chkIPRange.isSelected()==true){
        System.out.println("multi ip scan started");
        if(multiScanner==null && errorCheck()==0 || isScanning==false){
            isScanning=true;
            lstMessagesModel.clear();
            listListeningModel.clear();
            btnScan.setText("Stop");
            lstMessagesModel.addElement("Scan Started...");
            int p1 = Integer.parseInt(txtStartPort.getText());
            int p2 = Integer.parseInt(txtFinalPort.getText());

            try {
                InetAddress ip1 = InetAddress.getByName(txtTargetIP.getText());
                InetAddress ip2 = InetAddress.getByName(txtFiniship.getText());
                List<InetAddress> ipList = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

                int ip1Int = ByteBuffer.wrap(ip1.getAddress()).getInt();
                int ip2Int = ByteBuffer.wrap(ip2.getAddress()).getInt();

                for (int i = ip1Int; i <= ip2Int; i++) {
                    InetAddress ipName = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(i));
                    ipList.add(ipName);
                    System.out.println(ipName);
                }
                for (InetAddress ipSingle : ipList) {
                    multiScanner = new MultiThread(ipSingle, p1, p2, this);
                    multiScanner.start();
                    System.out.println("New Thread Started");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                lstMessagesModel.addElement("Unable to Connect");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see that I am creating a new instance of the multithread scanner for each ip address and that this is most likely the root of my problem, but I am unsure how to send a new ip address to the scanner without creating a new instance?

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain the "memory problems" in some more details? It looks like you are following the right logic as of now!

Comment: call run instead of start and the method is run sequentially

Comment: Use ThreadPoolExecutor with BlockingQueue

Comment: Err, don't multi-thread it?